# Update an TextView in NavigationDrawer after input from user in previous activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

There is some information that I want to display in the NavigationDrawer. This information is entered by the user in a previous activity. I use an intent to send the information to the Main Activity for the Drawer.

MainActivity (After user entered details)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String info = intent.getStringExtra("info");

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);


    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_dashboard);
            break;
            ......
    }
```

I have a specific layout for the navigation drawer and it contains a textview which I want to update with the String test. This is the fragment code and the xml for it.

FragmentDrawer Class

```
public FragmentDrawer() {

}

public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
    this.drawerListener = listener;
}

public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

    // preparing navigation drawer items
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        navItem.setIcon(icons.getResourceId(i,-1));
        data.add(navItem);
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // drawer labels
    titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    TextView userID = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.nav_title_user);

    adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    return layout;
}

public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

}
```

FramgentDrawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    ......

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceInverse"
        android:text="@string/welcome_user"
        android:id="@+id/nav_title_user"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container" />
```

I have managed to update the list in the drawer with Icons, Labels and a Header. I have done so by using a RecyclerViewAdapter.

The problem that I am having is that these details were from the resources (strings.xml).

How can I update a textview on a NavigationFragment when it has been created? How can I send a value to the fragment so that it will be used during OnCreateView of the fragment?

Comment: show your xml and code

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can u tell me how u updated the list items texts , for example "login" to "logout" ?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking too much into it. The solution was quite simple...Even though it took me 3 hrs to figure this out :/

In the NavigationFragment, I created a method to update a textview with a string. In the MainActivity where I get the information from the intent, I just called the method like this:

```
drawerFragment.setUserTextView(info);
```

This is why taking breaks are important... ^^

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can u tell me how u updated the list items texts , for example "login" to "logout" ?